# Почему не отменяет preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Я отменяю событие если поля пустые и когда они не будут пустые хочу включить событие

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        if(name.value.length || mail.value.length === 0){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            event.defaultPrevented();
        }
    });
```

как правильно написать скрипт? в чем я тут ошибся?

Comment: `defaultPrevented ` это вы откуда взяли такое?

Comment: если поля пустые отменяйте действие `preventDefault`, если все ок, то просто ничего не делайте

Answer (score 0):

это ваш скрипт в нормальном виде

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  name.value.length >= 0 && e.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

а это то что вам надо

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
 if(!name.value.trim()) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
 }
});
```